# Django Query ForeignKeys to return a list "grouped by"

Tags: python, django

Something is tricking my mind here.
My mission is to get a list of Categories vs Brands, querying over Products models.

Say we got something like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) #examples: TVs, Monitors, HomeTheaters, Fridges

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) #examples: Sony, LG, Apple

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I am looking for is a query that could return me something like this:
    {TVs: [Sony, LG, Apple], Monitors:[Sony, Apple] }
Of course it could return a queryset that I could transform into a dict later.

Since I couldn't get this done in a clean way, I did this:

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
products = Product.objects.select_related('category', 'brand').all()

categories_brands = {}
for category in categories:
    categories_brands[category.name] = []
for product in products:
    if product.brand.name not in categories_brands[product.category.name]:
        category_brands[product.category.name].append(product.brand.name)
```

It does work. But feels silly iterating like that. I tried "annotate" and "regroup" solutions in templatetags, but I couldn't make it work.

In addition to this question... would you have one Model class for all the products or best would be have Fridge class, TV's class and so on. I am using tags to add content like volume of a fridge and size of a monitor to filter it later. Maybe you experts can give me some advise on this as well.

Thanks in advance.

Felipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can perform this in a single query, and use [**`itertools.groupby`** [doc]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this:

```
from django.db.models import F
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

qs = Product.objects.annotate(
    category_name=F('category__name')
    brand_name=F('brand__name')
).values('category_name', 'brand_name').order_by('category_name').distinct()

result = {
    k: [v['brand_name'] for v in vs]
    for k, vs in groupby(qs, itemgetter('category_name'))
}
```

We thus first query the database for `category`s and `brand`s, and we obtain a `QuerySet` that contains a `'category_name'` key, and a `'brand_name'` key, for your sample data it would look like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'category_name': 'Monitors', 'brand_name': 'Sony'},
    {'category_name': 'Monitors', 'brand_name': 'Apple'},
    {'category_name': 'TVs', 'brand_name': 'Sony'},
    {'category_name': 'TVs', 'brand_name': 'Apple'},
    {'category_name': 'TVs', 'brand_name': 'LG'}
 ]>
```

Then we can perform a single pass over the queryset, and populate the dictionary.

Comment: Queryset worked. Also learned about F(), which is great.
Transpose queryset into groupby dict failed. Returned proper keys but all of them got a list with the same values.
Something like this:

'TVs': ['Sony', 'Sony', 'Consul', 'Apple', 'LG'],
'Monitors':  ['Sony', 'Sony', 'Consul', 'Apple', 'LG'],
'HomeTheaters': ['Sony', 'Sony', 'Consul', 'Apple', 'LG'],

Fixing it using groupby and itemgetter was still far too advance for me, so I simply iterated over the queryset to make it it work as I needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, it should now be fixed.

Comment: Works perfect now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ...

```
query = Product.objects.select_related('category', 'brand').all().query
query.group_by = ['category']
results = QuerySet(query=query, model=Product)
```